# Macros: Variables inside of variables

Tags: variable, macro, craft4

I have a slightly mind bending question. Here's my setup:

**file.twig**

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'events').all() %}
{% set tileContent %}
    <p>{{tileEntry.title}}</p>
{% endset %}
{% import "macros.twig" as generalMacros %}
{{ generalMacros.renderTile(entries, tileContent) }}
```

**macros.twig**

```
{% macro renderTile(entries, tileContent) %}
  {%- for tileEntry in entries %}
    <div>
        {{tileContent}}
    </div>
  {% endfor -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

So my macro variable `tileContent` contains `tileEntry.title`, which refers to the `tileEntry` generated in the macro's `for` loop.

However, when I run this, the variable of `tileEntry` is not picked up in the macro's loop, and so nothing is output - in fact I get an error that `tileEntry` isn't defined... which is correct as it's defined inside the `for` loop inside `macros.twig`

I can't seem to pass a variable to a macro that contains a reference to a variable generated by that macro... oy.

**Why do I want to do this?**

So that we never have to edit **macros.twig** — all we need to do is edit **file.twig** and pass it content through the variable `{{tileContent}}` and use variables inside the macro to customize it.

Basically the contents of `tileContent` are being interpreted before they are being sent to the macro, whereas I'd like it to be interpreted inside the macro first.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? And if so, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (probably better/simpler) solution, inspired by @JamesSmith's comment, uses `embed` to avoid includes inside of macros, and has all the same flexibility:

**file.twig**

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'events').all() %}
{% embed "/_partials/tiles.twig" with {'entries':entries}  %}
    {% block captionContent %}
        <h1>{{entry.title}}</h2>
        <p class='datestamp'>{{entry.eventDate | date('yy/m/d')}}</p>
        <p>{{entry.lead}}</p>
    {% endblock %}  
{% endembed %}
```

**/_partials/tiles.twig**

```
<div>
    {%- for entry in entries %}
        <div>
            {% block captionContent %}
                {# Default Content Overridden by 'embed'/'block' Call  #}
                <p>Hello World!</p>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endfor -%}
</div>
```

This way the `block` is called on the loop as if it was in scope of the parent page and overrides the default content inside. But if the block is not provided then the default content inside each loop is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...
So in my search I was looking for a twig way to do something similar to php's eval and  came across the [twig function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html) `template_from_string()`

The sample code from twig's docs looks like this: `{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}")) }}`

So I can create a string in my `file.twig` that's eval'd only when it's "included" in `macros.twig`.

**Here is what that looks like:**

**file.twig**

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'events').all() %}
{% set tileContent = template_from_string("<p>{{tileEntry.title}}</p>") %}
{% import "macros.twig" as generalMacros %}
{{ generalMacros.renderTile(entries, tileContent) }}
```

**macros.twig**

```
{% macro renderTile(entries, tileContent) %}
  {%- for tileEntry in entries %}
    <div>
        {{include(tileContent)}}
    </div>
  {% endfor -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

This way the variable string `tileContent` is not actually evaluated in context until it's "included" in `macros.twig` when we output `{{include(tileContent)}}`.

Comment: Feels like you might be over-complicating things here? Have you tried using an `embed`? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html

Comment: @JamesSmith — Well hot damn!!! That is much simpler. Thank you! — I'll post another answer with a refactored solution using `embed`